# Is it possible to use mouse gestures without pressing a key?

Tags: mouse, gestures

Is it possible to use Easystroke (or other program) without an initiate key?

Because there is no key for it on the tablet (JooJoo).

I hope you know what i try to explain. --> mouse gestures in Black&White (the game) - style :-D

Comment: I would like to achieve the same. At least, to tap once and then perform the gesture... My touchpad's buttons are too hard. I rather press a keyboard key instead.

Answer (score 1):

You can use EasyStroke using mouse buttons rather than keys. If you uncheck all of the modifier keys, you can use plain left or right button mouse gestures.

Comment: Oh no.... :-D
I mean without pressing anything! Like on smartphones or tablets.

Comment: On a tablet, this should work if it supports a double-tap to click like many touchpads. You would then do double-tap-drag to perform your gesture. If it doesn't support this I think you may be stuck. You can try removing all control buttons from Easystroke ... I can't try it right now so I'm not sure it will work.